# update list with specific object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

im using the following code to get data from list of object

```
Con preConObj = preConfigList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == con.ID);
```

Now I want to update this object In the preConfigList which is type

```
 private static List<Con> preConList;
```

with this object

```
Con PostConObj
```

What is the best way to do that ?

I've tried with

`preConObj = postConObj` but this does not update the list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would first find the index of the object using:

```
var idx = preConList.FindIndex(x => x.ID == preConObj.ID);
preConList[idx] = postConObj; // replace it
```

Answer (score 0):

Reflection can be useful in this case:

```
public static void UpdateObject<T>(this T source, T target)
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    foreach(var prop in properties)
        prop.SetValue(source, prop.GetValue(target));
}

// Usage:
preConObj.UpdateObject(postConObj);
```

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood the question, don't you think?

Comment: @AmitJoki no actually your way also should work and it's more simple. but this also works with other collections, since not all collections have a FindIndex method

Comment: thanks for that clarification... I thought I had provided a wrong solution, when you used reflection..